# Highcharts Fill pattern color based on some condition

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, colors, stacked-area-chart

I am using Highcharts fill pattern to fill the area, but I want two fill colors based on the data. If the area is below zero on the x-axis then that area should be in different color than the positive area. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.negativeFillColor

Comment: You can also see zones if you need more flexibility - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bellcurve.zones